# Mime type for custom text format ignored by mobile Safari

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, mime-types

I have a custom json based format that I need opened as `application/octet-stream`.

I've set `.htaccess` to read..

```
AddType application/octet-stream .custom
```

Where my custom files use the `.custom` extension ie. `document.custom`

When I open the directory in Chrome, Chromium or Safari on OS X, the file is assumed as `application/octet-stream` properly and goes straight to download.

Mobile Safari (iOS6) opens it as `plain/text` and displays it in the browser, the type is registered as the UTI of an App, and from mail attachments, opens properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the exact same problem: It seems like if the website fails to provide a sufficiently informative mime-type in its content header, it becomes difficult to override Safari's treatment of it. Stuff like this makes me sad.

Comment: I'd forgotten all about this, I believe there's no way to override safari's treatment, which is really a bit negligent of the Safari team. I have yet to try it with iOS7 though.

Comment: Yeah, hopefully soon Safari will become more intelligent about this. The good thing though is that there is usually a number of workarounds such as Dropbox, various mail apps, etc. including Mail.app, which take more of a hands-off approach and generally let you pass the file into your app.

Comment: At the time this was originally posted DropBox was using the incorrect Mime type too. I'll have to try it now and see.

Comment: Yeah, I'd imagine if Dropbox is capable of opening whatever file it is, then theres not anything (similarly to our situation with Safari) to control whether to let it *let you use your app* for the file. The Safari situation's slightly better because if you have control over your webserver you make it send the right mime-type (one that guarantees Safari will leave it alone)

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't appear to be working with non-binary files. I have a custom binary which opens (always did too) in DropBox, and a custom json style data format, which just opens as text in DropBox but doesn't see the app.  I will have to check everything is configured as expected, but this is a duplicate test/result pattern from when I built the app originally. I'll have a proper look soon as I can, and see if the result is legitimately an issue with DropBox (or if I screwed up.)

Comment: ^ Definitely a DropBox issue.

Comment: Dropbox (the one I'm using...) has a dedicated "open to" icon (which is an arrow into a box) which will bring up the "open in..." iOS menu, and my app shows up in here without fail. It will do this even after opening up the text-file. So it is indeed always possible for me to use dropbox to get stuff open in my app now.

Comment: I too have that icon, latest update installed... however, it fails to open the file in the right app, if it's plaintext (regardless of UTI mapping), UTI mapped binary is ok.  But only Mail.app opens the plaintext file in the correct app.